# libreoffie calc macro to paste formula

Tags: macros, formula, libreoffice, calc

I want a macro to paste a standard Libreoffice formula.
The formula is:
`=IF(D13<>"",VLOOKUP(E13, $Jnr_ranking_processor.$C$11:$G$50, 5, 0),"")`

I have a Form Control button to trigger the below macro.

```
Sub AssignFormulaToCell
' Source: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/calc_functions.html
REM Add a formula to cell I13. Function name must be in English.
    oCell = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByIndex(0).getCellRangeByName("I13")
    oCell.Formula = "=IF($D13<>"",VLOOKUP($E13, $Jnr_ranking_processor.$C$11:$G$50, 5, 0),"")"
REM Cell I13 displays the localized function name
End Sub
```

When the button is pressed, I13 reports "TRUE" Why? The 'raw' forumla before using macros gives the actual lookup value.

This macro needs to be pasted into from I13 to I43. How to get the macro the row for D and E in the vlookup to be the same as the row where the macro is to be pasted. Surely one doesn't have write in effect 20 macro's with each one having a manually adjusted row. {I'm not sure how to write a for loop with an iterable in a formula.}

Thanks for any help/advice offered.

Comment: First, [**use a semicolon instead of a comma**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/why-does-calc-get-confused-by-setformula-max-4-5-3/18672/2?u=johnsun). Secondly, don't forget that quotes inside a literal string must be doubled, `""` instead `"`, `""""` instead `""` (just look at the formula in I13 that your code creates - you'll immediately see the error)

Comment: Aaaah yes,. Thank you JohnSUN.
I get the correct vlookup data now.
For the benefit of amateurs like me, this is what it looks like now...

oCell.Formula = "=IF(D13<>"""";VLOOKUP(E13; $Jnr_ranking_processor.$C$11:$G$50; 5; 0);"""")"

V. Kind of you to help and so quickly too. :)

Any advice on how to get the increment thing working?
I have about 30 rows where this needs to be done repeated for 20 columns That's an eye-watering 600 macro's (in effect) I'd have to hand copy and paste.

Comment: It seems to me that [**this message**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-write-libreoffice-calc-starbasic-macro-code-for-vlookup-which-i-get-easily-in-formula-and-functions-in-lo-calc/84652/6?u=johnsun) is the answer to your question.

Comment: I recorded a macro where I dragged the "macro pasted formula" down through all the rows in one column, and the relative cell references worked - they incremented/updated/changed correctly!! :) I placed the recorded macro code into the AssignFormulaToCell Sub above and it's works fine. But it would be very nice to learn how to directly code the increment. Tq again JohnSUN.